# How to test if an exception was thrown?

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, assertj

My code:

```
public String getTemplate(TestType fileType) {
    Util util = new Util();
    try {
        return util.addPrefix(util.getTemplate(fileType));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn(e.getMessage());
        throw new MyException(...);
    } catch (SyntaxException e) {
        logger.warn(e.getMessage());
        throw new MyException(...);
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
TestType testType = TestType.main;
Util util = spy(new Util()); //or Util util = mock(Util.class);
when(util.getTemplate(testType)).thenThrow(new SyntaxException(...)); //or IOException

String out = runService.getTemplate(testType);
```

But it doesn't work. Since this method creates a new class.
Is it possible to mock the creation of a new inner class without using PowerMock?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mockito Test Exception Expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873519/mockito-test-exception-expected)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using junit and `assertThrows` function. You can find more info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-assert-exception)

Some time ago I wrote this test.

```
try {
    Mockito.when(tagDao.findAllTags()).thenReturn(expectedTagList);
    TagService tagService = new TagServiceImpl(tagDao);
    List<Tag> actualTagList = tagService.findAllTags();
    assertEquals(actualTagList, expectedTagList);
} catch (DaoException | ServiceException e) {
    fail(e);
}
```

You can try to change `fail(e)` to `assertEquals` or smth else, that will validate your exception.

If you will ask me which approach is better, I will say that the first one is more understandable and easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't check for any throws in tested code. Your test class only mocks behaviour of "getTemplate()" by calling .thenThrow on:

```
    csvUtil.getTemplate(testType)
```

If you want to check if exception is thrown you can use many assertion libraries. For example using junit.jupiter you can perform it by calling:

```
        assertThatExceptionOfType(YourExceptionClass.class)
                .isThrownBy(() -> csvUtil.getTemplate(testType));
```

you can additionally (if needed) check if that exception had specific message for example:

```
        assertThatExceptionOfType(YourExceptionClass.class)
                .isThrownBy(() ->
                       csvUtil.getTemplate(testType)
                ).withMessage("expected message here");
```

Comment: the problem is that I can't cause errors manually, my code works well. so when the method is called in the test class, it works completely without errors
I want to manually create an error when calling util.getTemplate() method

Comment: You shouldn't mock tested class. You should prepare scenario when it SHOULD throw that exception and implement it. 
For example if you are trying to trying to add prefix think of a data that would throw that exception and pass it to tested method